# Using Javascript, I am trying to persist the data in SessionStorage and localStorage of browser but after refreshing the page the data is lost

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, session-storage

I am adding array of movie objects to session storage in below line as :

sessionStorage.setItem('MyMovieList', JSON.stringify(movies));

Could someone figure out what is wrong in the code because of which session storage is not working as expected?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale=2.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <title>Putting User input into JS Objects</title>
            <style>
    
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form>
                <div class="formBox">
                    <label for="title">Movie</label>
                    <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title"/>
                </div>
                <div class="formBox>
                    <label for="yr">Year</label>
                    <input type="number" id="yr" placeholder="Year"/>
                </div>
                <div class="formBox">
                    <button id="btn">Click to Add</button>
                </div>
                <div id="msg">
                    <pre></pre>
                </div>
            </form>
            <script>
                let movies = [];
                const addMovie = (ev) => {
                    ev.preventDefault();//to stop the form submission
    
                    let movie = {
                        id: Date.now(),
                        title: document.getElementById('title').value,
                        year: document.getElementById('yr').value
                    }
    
                movies.push(movie);
                document.forms[0].reset();// to clear the form for next entry
                //document.querySelector('form').reset();
                //for display purpose only
                console.warn('added', {movies} );
                let pre =  document.querySelector('#msg pre');
                pre.textContent = '\n' + JSON.stringify(movies, '\t', 2);
                
                //saving to localStorage
                //localStorage.setItem('MyMovieList', JSON.stringify(movies ));
    
                //saving to sessionStorage
                sessionStorage.setItem('MyMovieList', JSON.stringify(movies));
                }
                 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                   document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',addMovie);
                 });
    
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify(movies, '\t', 2);` does not match the definition for the method, for the second parameter.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify  It's expected to be a function, or an array, or null

Comment: How do you know its not working? Did you see an error message? Did you look at the sessionStorage using browser debug?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think that "session storage" is just that: for this specific session, and "local storage" persists over sessions.

Comment: Also, I don't see where you parse the data from local storage.

Comment: @MikeMurphy : i checked at file:// under Storage in Developer Tools of Chrome.

Comment: Not sure what file:// means in Chrome Developer Tools.  I use the Application Tab.  This shows Local Session, SessionStorage etc.

Answer (score 0):

So I copied your code and ran it locally and everything worked fine, the movies are stored in the section. The problem you are having is that

```
`let pre =  document.querySelector('#msg pre');
            pre.textContent = '\n' + JSON.stringify(movies, '\t', 2);`
```

is inside the clickHandler so on refresh if you want to see what you had in you `session` you can just click the button and it will be displayed within the `pre` tag again. try this instead

```
  <script>
let movies = [];
const addMovie = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();//to stop the form submission

  let movie = {
    id: Date.now(),
    title: document.getElementById('title').value,
    year: document.getElementById('yr').value
  }

  movies.push(movie);
  document.forms[0].reset();// to clear the form for next entry
  //document.querySelector('form').reset();
  //for display purpose only
  console.warn('added', { movies });

  //saving to localStorage
  //localStorage.setItem('MyMovieList', JSON.stringify(movies ));

  //saving to sessionStorage
  sessionStorage.setItem('MyMovieList', JSON.stringify(movies));

  let pre = document.querySelector('#msg pre');
  pre.textContent = '\n' + sessionStorage.getItem('MyMovieList'),
    '\t', 2;
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addMovie);
  let pre = document.querySelector('#msg pre');
  pre.textContent = '\n' + sessionStorage.getItem('MyMovieList'),
    '\t', 2;
});
```

In the `addMovie` function just save to the `sessioStorage` and display to again, meanwhile on refresh you the `DOMContentLoaded` just display whatever you had in the `sessionStore`.

NB - you might want to format the output the way you want and maybe refactor the duplicate code into a function to make it DRY, I hope this suggestions is useful and can unblock you so that you can continue building your amazing app. #cheers

Comment: @Victor : Thanks for your suggestion, i tried removing that piece of code and updated the code as you said but still it didnot work.